# System account dont have permission to start sharepoint workflow 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a problem with sharepoint 2013 workflow as 2010 platform. If a Site Collection Administrator or system account or any user starts the workflow manually or publishes the workflow with "start workflow when item created or modified" checkbox, I get this error:
[image: error message]

this error just appear for specific web application!!
Does anybody have any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try to publish and run the WF with non system account. There are few issues with trying to run things in SP2013 with system account (I think it lacks the Claims)

Comment: this problem continuous with any user with contribute permission!

Comment: What messages you get from the ULS logs when permission issue happens?

Answer (score 1):

Beside @Marek Sarad answer, make sure that all Authentication methods have been **enabled** else `Digest Authentication` and `Basic Authentication`

**Steps :**

- Open IIS > go to sites.
- Select your SharePoint web application > Click on Authentication
- Make sure that all Authentication has been enabled else `Digest Authentication` and `Basic Authentication`

Comment: Why do you advise this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the System Account to start the work, then you need to activate the App Permission feature.

- Go to Site Settings > Site Features
- On this page activate " Workflow can use app permission"

Other way is don't use the System Account for the workflows. Check this [Workflows do not start](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/victorbutuza/2009/03/14/workflows-do-not-start/)